# cron job with error php deprecation - str_replace(): Passing null to parameter

Tags: php, cron-job, deprecated

I'm curing a Joomla instance CiviCRM. Just updated from Joomla 3 to joomla 4.4.1 with CiviCRM 5.68.1. 
Updated too the server debian version from 11 to 12. 
configured cron task with cv version v0.3.48

`/opt/cv api job.execute --user=XXXX --quiet --cwd=/var/www/html/XXXX/htdocs`

Got this message :

> [PHP Deprecation] str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type array|string is deprecated at /var/www/html/XXXX/htdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Joomla.php:525

How can I get rid of this error ?

Answer (score 0):

You could replace line 525 with `return $locale ? str_replace('-', '_', $locale) : NULL;`

I don't know enough about joomla to tell you why it can't determine your language. Possibly this is normal if it has no default, or maybe it is not set in your joomla site/user settings.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'll doublecheck that language is defined.